# Dotnetnuke Installation; Microsoft SQL Server 'sa' Account Problems

Tags: sql-server, passwords

So I've been tasked to install DNN onto my system. I am using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer. I am being asked for the password for the 'sa' account. I do not know the password for the account. So when I tried to use the Microsoft SQL Server Management software to change the password I get the following message:

**"Change password failed for Login 'sa' (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) 
Additional Information: 
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) 
Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)"**

How would I obtain permission to change the password? Or am I missing the point entirely and should be doing something else to install the software??

I would assume the issue lies with SQL, what steps should I take to rectify this problem??

Comment: SQL Server uses either/both of "Windows authentication" and "SQL Server authentication".  By default, MSSQL installs with *ONLY* "Windows authentication". "sa" requires MSSQL authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server uses either/both of "Windows authentication" and "SQL Server authentication".

By default, MSSQL installs with ONLY "Windows authentication". "sa" requires MSSQL authentication.

SOLUTION:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

1) Go into SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.

2) On the Security page, under Server authentication, select the new server authentication mode, and then click OK.

3) In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.

4) In Object Explorer, right-click your server, and then click Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to login via Windows Authentication and change it that way? If so, that would be the best way to do it.

If the only account that has admin access is the sa account though, then you can try starting SQL server in single user mode and then resetting the sa password. Note that this method requires local admin access to the server itself.

http://sigkillit.com/2013/01/02/recover-sa-password-on-microsoft-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you could login with the SA account into SQL server, it will likely prompt you to change your password (first time logging in) and then you would be good to go after that.

That being said, I never recommend setting up DNN to connect to SQL server with the SA account. Each DNN database should have its own DB user, that way if one DNN install gets compromised for some reason, they can't reach out into other databases on the same server.

EDIT: a little more info

From http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/1 
In SQL Server you should go through and create a new database. I always create a database with the same name as the website, so in this case DNNDEV.ME. Once you have created the database, create a user that can access that database. I always use SQL authentication, turn off the enforce password requirements, and give the user DB Owner and Public access to the DNNDEV.ME database. Remember the username and password you create here as you will need them when you walk through the Installation screen for DotNetNuke.